# Rearrange HTML Focused Tab's Row on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm porting a program from `XAML/C#` to `HTML/CSS/JavaScript`.

I have tabbed sections which rearrange the focused tab's row to the bottom when clicked. This is automatically performed by the `TabControl` in XAML.

---

**XAML/C#**

General Focused

[image: tabs 1]

Video Focused

[image: tabs 2]

---

**HTML/CSS/JavaScript**

[image: tabs 3]

How can I do the same with JavaScript?

I'm using this script https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_tabulators.asp

```js
// Display Tab Section

function OpenTab(tabName) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tabSection");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.btnTab {
  width: 33.33%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: #020f31;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.2em;
  border-top: 1px solid #0080cb;
  border-right: 1px solid #0080cb;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #0080cb;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Tabs -->
<div id="sectionTabs">
  <button class="btnTab" onclick="OpenTab('General')">General</button>
  <button class="btnTab" onclick="OpenTab('Stream')">Stream</button>
  <button class="btnTab" onclick="OpenTab('Display')">Display</button>
  <button class="btnTab" onclick="OpenTab('Video')">Video</button>
  <button class="btnTab" onclick="OpenTab('Audio')">Audio</button>
  <button class="btnTab" onclick="OpenTab('Subtitles')">Subtitles</button>
</div>

<!-- Sections -->
<div id="General" class="tabSection">
  General ...
</div>
<div id="Stream" class="tabSection" style="display:none">
  Stream ...
</div>
<div id="Display" class="tabSection" style="display:none">
  Display ...
</div>
<div id="Video" class="tabSection" style="display:none">
  Video ...
</div>
<div id="Audio" class="tabSection" style="display:none">
  Audio ...
</div>
<div id="Subtitles" class="tabSection" style="display:none">
  Subtitles ...
</div>
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/kq183ato/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you can change markup a little bit like wrapping the first row and second row of the buttons on different div...

Also try to avoid inline javascript and use `data-attributes` here

**Steps:**

- create a new array instance from iterable object `y` usinf `Array.from`
- add a click event on all the buttons using `addEventListener`
- hide all the elements containing `tabSection` class and also remove `active` class from all the buttons using for loop.
- get the `data-tab` value from clicked button and set `display:block` to the respected tab and also add `active` class to the current button.
- now for switching the `.first` and `.second` div up and down use `insertBefore` inside the `if` condition to compare the index of the clicked button

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tabSection");
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("btnTab");;
var a = document.querySelector(".first");
var b = document.querySelector(".second")
var p = document.getElementById("sectionTabs");
Array.from(y).forEach(function(elem, index) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
      y[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
    var tab = this.getAttribute("data-tab");
    document.getElementById(tab).style.display = "block";
    this.classList.add("active");
    if (index < 3) {
      p.insertBefore(b, p.childNodes[0])
    } else {
      p.insertBefore(a, p.childNodes[0])
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.btnTab {
  width: 33.33%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: #020f31;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.2em;
  border-top: 1px solid #0080cb;
  border-right: 1px solid #0080cb;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #0080cb;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.btnTab.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Tabs -->
<div id="sectionTabs">
  <div class="first">
    <button class="btnTab" data-tab="General">General</button>
    <button class="btnTab" data-tab="Stream">Stream</button>
    <button class="btnTab" data-tab="Display">Display</button>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <button class="btnTab active" data-tab="Video">Video</button>
    <button class="btnTab" data-tab="Audio">Audio</button>
    <button class="btnTab" data-tab="Subtitles">Subtitles</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Sections -->
<div id="General" class="tabSection" style="display:none">
  General ...
</div>
<div id="Stream" class="tabSection" style="display:none">
  Stream ...
</div>
<div id="Display" class="tabSection" style="display:none">
  Display ...
</div>
<div id="Video" class="tabSection">
  Video ...
</div>
<div id="Audio" class="tabSection" style="display:none">
  Audio ...
</div>
<div id="Subtitles" class="tabSection" style="display:none">
  Subtitles ...
</div>
```

**Reference Link:**

- [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [element.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)
- [node.insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

Comment: I will try it in my project, I think it will work well.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by adding a bit more code to `OpenTab()`.

First of all, to check whether a button in the top row or bottom row was pressed, you may add classes `row1` to the first row of buttons and `row2` to the second row. Then, you can check which button was pressed in `OpenTab()` by passing in `this` as an additional parameter: `onclick="OpenTab(this, 'General')`.

With these changes to HTML, the javascript can be changed to change the button pressed into account. In the code below, each `if` statement checks that the current button is in a particular row with `elem.classList.contains("rowX")` and that the row is the top row with `parent.firstElementChild.classList.contains("rowX")`. It then loops through the number of tabs in the row (amount of tabs can vary) and places them in the beginning of the `#sectionTabs` div.

```
function OpenTab(elem, tabName) { // Note that `elem` is where `this` is passed
    // Your original code
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tabSection");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";

    // Additional code
    row1_elem = document.getElementsByClassName("row1"); // initially top row
    row2_elem = document.getElementsByClassName("row2"); // initially bottom row
    parent = document.getElementById("sectionTabs");

    // check that button in top row was clicked
    if (elem.classList.contains("row1") == 1 && parent.firstElementChild.classList.contains("row1") == 1) {

      // move elements from bottom row up
      for (var j = 0; j < row2_elem.length; j++) {
        parent.insertBefore(row2_elem[row2_elem.length-1], parent.firstChild);
      }

    // check that button in top row was clicked
    } else if (elem.classList.contains("row2") == 1 && parent.firstElementChild.classList.contains("row2") == 1) {

      // move elements from bottom row up
      for (var j = 0; j < row1_elem.length; j++) {
        parent.insertBefore(row1_elem[row1_elem.length-1], parent.firstChild);
      }

    }
}
```

A jsfiddle is also available:

https://jsfiddle.net/o687eLyb/

Note that you could also wrap the rows into separate divs with IDs `rowX` and use slightly different logic to check which row was pressed; however, this answer has the benefit that it keeps HTML structure the same.